# AES CTR symmetric encryption and decryption

Tags: c, openssl, aes, encryption-symmetric

I am not an expert in openssl. I have put together the following code to encrypt and decrypt a message using AES-CTR. The output is not what I expect to see.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h> //for RAND_bytes function

struct ctr_state {
    unsigned char ivec[16];  /* ivec[0..7] is the IV, ivec[8..15] is the big-endian counter */
    unsigned int num;
    unsigned char ecount[16];
};

int init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, const unsigned char iv[8])
{
    /* aes_ctr128_encrypt requires 'num' and 'ecount' set to zero on the
    * first call. */
    state->num = 0;
    memset(state->ecount, 0, 16);
    /* Initialise counter in 'ivec' to 0 */
    memset(state->ivec + 8, 0, 8);
    /* Copy IV into 'ivec' */
    memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 8);
    return(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char key[] = "thiskeyisverybad"; // It is 128bits though..
    unsigned char iv[8];
    struct ctr_state state;
    if (!RAND_bytes(iv, 8))
         printf("\nError in RAND_Bytes...\n");
    init_ctr(&state, iv);
    AES_KEY aes_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes_key);
    char msg[] = "hey";
    unsigned char cipher[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    char plain[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    AES_ctr128_encrypt((unsigned char *) msg, cipher, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, &aes_key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);
    AES_ctr128_encrypt(cipher, (unsigned char *) plain, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, &aes_key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);
    printf("\nPLAIN:%s\n", plain);
    return 0;
}
```

The result I am getting is something like this: "PLAIN:¢u∩U└■My&nu9♫_╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠"Åä▬♂☻e0T   ç§▓→♀v╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠hey"

Any idea what causes this? All I want to do is to use AES using CTR to encrypt and decrypt messages. I want to get the same encrypted length as the plaintext (or +1 byte). I have done this with DES but DES is not secure. I will then use the AES-CTR to encrypt and decrypt my network traffic (stream).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset before decrypt:

```
…
init_ctr(&state, iv);
AES_ctr128_encrypt(
        cipher,
        (unsigned char *) plain,
        AES_BLOCK_SIZE,
        &aes_key,
        state.ivec,
        state.ecount,
        &state.num
        );
printf("\nPLAIN:%s\n", plain);
```